# All buttons effecting one element instead of respective elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am having trouble using the same function for multiple buttons. I am able to get my buttons to work but only work within one element. I do not want to have to write different functions for every comment section. I would like to be able to use same function when submitting comment to respective elements. Thank you for any help in advance.

Code for reference :

```
<div class="comment-area">
  
      <h3>Leave A Comment</h3>
     <div>
        <textarea placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
        
        <button class="submitBtn">Comment</button>
        <button class="button">Cancel</button>
        
      </div>
      <div class="addComment"></div>
  
</div>

<div class="comment-area">
  
      <h3>Leave A Comment</h3>
     <div>
        <textarea placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
        
        <button class="submitBtn">Comment</button>
        <button class="button">Cancel</button>
        
     </div>
      
  <div class="addComment"></div>
  
</div>

let comment = document.querySelector("textarea");
let submitBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".submitBtn");
let commentArea = document.querySelector(".addComment");

submitBtn.forEach((btn)=>{
  btn.addEventListener("click", addComment);
});

function addComment(e){
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("comment");
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.innerText = comment.value;
  newDiv.appendChild(newLi);
  commentArea.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `commentArea`, append `newLi` to `this.parentElement.nextElementSibling`.

Comment: This gives me the same comment value in both sections coming from first comment text area

Comment: Sure, because `comment` needs also be replaced  with `this.previousElementSibling`. You can't fix the target elements beforehand, they've to be queried dynamically in the event handler.

Comment: Thank you, again!